# Append string into a list

Tags: python, loops

I would like to loop through a list in python and usually I do in this way:

let's imagine a list into a variable called 'movie' where I want to print the even into a variable 'authors' and the odd into 'stars'. I would do like this:

```
stars = movies[0] #print the first
authors = movies[1] #print the second

for i in range(0, len(movies), 2):
    stars = movies[0+i]
    authors = movies[1+i]
```

But how can i do in this other way?

```
stars, authors = movies[0:2]

for i in range(0, len(movies), 2):
    stars #how can i insert "i"?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use slicing:

```
stars=movies[::2]
authors=movies[1::2]
```

`stars` consists of every other sample in the `movies` array, hence the step of 2. It starts with the 0th index, which was omitted above. You could also write `stars=movies[0::2]`.

`authors` also uses a step of 2, but starts with the first index in `movies`.

You can check out the basics of indexing and slicing [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/extension/python/notes/node29.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need the value of movies afterwards you can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

```
while movies:
    stars, authors, *movies = movies
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use triple slicing (start:end:step):

```
stars, authors = movies[::2], movies[1::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(movies), 2):
    stars, authors = movies[i:i+2]
```